# Решить проблему с преобразованием типов данных Python

Tags: python, строки

Код пайтон:

```
text = "5+5"
print( text )
```

В консоле вместо 10 получаю "5+5"

Как преобразовать переменную text с типом string ("5+5") в int (10)?

Comment: eval посмотрите

Comment: Больше подробностей, пожалуйста. Какую задачу вы решаете? Почему вас не устраивает `print(10)`? Какие ещё действия могут быть внутри строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильное решение — распарсить.

Быстрое и опасное — eval

```
text = "5+5"
print(eval (text))
```

Если кратко, опасность eval'а состоит в том что, если строка получена извне и не прошла глубокую проверку, то внутри может оказаться что угодно от относительно безобидной команды на стирание всех доступных данных, до инструкций запуска проекта злоумышленников по распределённому взлому ядерных ключей Пентагона. Так что бездумное использование оного вполне может стать причиной начала атомной войны.

Comment: Раз упомянули опасность `eval()` опишите почему. И при написании кода соблюдайте [`PEP8`](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id10)

Comment: Спасибо, это поможет реализовать следующий код:
http://prntscr.com/hp5t8o

Answer (score 3):

Для версии 3.6+

```
f'{5+5}' # выведет 10
```

Eval это плохо и опасно.

```
eval ( "__import__('os').remove('very_important_file')") # удалит нужный файл
```